# How to run HRM for webpack 5 with npm/yarn link?

Tags: webpack

HRM in webpack 5+ is not working with npm link. I have `{ symlink : false }` and `{ followsymlinks : true }` in watch options.

There is a GitHub issue here for this specific problem:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6845

Here is a snippet from my webpack.conf

```
{
  mode: 'development',
  watchOptions: {
    followSymlinks: true,
  },
  entry: [
     require.resolve('./polyfills'),
     require.resolve('babel-polyfill'),
     require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?http://0.0.0.0:3001',
     require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
     paths.appIndexJs,
  ],
  output: {
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: '',

    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
         path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
      ),
      symlinks: false,
      extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    }
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
    alias: {
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        'react': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules', 'react')
    },
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle and configuration attempts, in my case, I've found that it was due to cache. To prevent rebuild duration significant increase every time you add changes, cache all `node_modules` but your local library using this config (from [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#managedpaths)):

```js
snapshot: {
    managedPaths: [
      /^(.+?[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!(@azure[\\/]msal-browser))(@.+?[\\/])?.+?)[\\/]/,
    ],
  },
```

In the regex, replace `@azure[\\/]msal-browser` with the name of your package (keep `[\\/]`). If you want to exclude a specific package author, just keep `@author` instead.

Keep `symlink: false`. `followSymlinks: true` seemed not to do anything.